# How to use Docker install file.deb offline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, caching, deb

I'm going to install file .deb on my container using Docker.
In my Dockerfire, i run a command below:
RUN apt-get install -y ./fonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb

```
ROOT Folder
 |->Dockerfire
         |->fonts
              |-> ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Note that: The file ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb is very light. When install this file, i see my Docker call another url to download file font then install it.

THE QUESTION:
How to install this package offline, i mean how to download all font and store in code and run install.
Because when call url to download font is very slow. So i want to download all and just install it.

Comment: Do you do `COPY` of the `.deb` installer in previous stage? If you don't do that, docker won't find that package and it will try to download from a repo url.

Comment: like `COPY ./fonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb .` and then do `RUN apt-get install -y ./ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb`

Answer (score 0):

apt doesn't do any curl operations. It must be written in an pre-install scripts.

you can check it by unzipping the deb file and look for deb/DEBIAN/preinstall

and change the script accordingly(ie. remove the curl and pack the font in the deb)

and then repack the deb file using `dpkg -b`

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html